# $x^n + y^n = z^n$, $n>1$ To show that $x,y,z$ is greater than $n$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

Problem: If $x$,$y$,$z$ and $n>1$ are natural numbers with $$x^n+y^n = z^n$$ then show that x,y and z are all greater then $n$.

My approach, from Fermat's Theorem we know that $x^n + y^n = z^n$ does not hold for $n>2$. And since there doesn't exist any triplet $x,y,z \in \{1,2\}$, $x,y,z$ will always be greater than $n$.

Here is the approach given in the book,
$$z>x,y$$
Suppose,$$y\ge x$$
Since, $z>y$, we have $z\ge y+1$. Now
$$ x^n = z^n - y^n$$
$$=(z-y)(z^{n-1}+z^{n-2}y+...y^{n-1})$$
$$>((y+1)-y)nx^{n-1}$$
(This above step is what I do not understand)
then,
$$x^n>nx^{n-1}$$or$$ x>n$$

What I do not understand is the third step and from where did the $nx^{n-1}$ come? Also is my proof not correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you are supposed to be using Fermat's Last Theorem to prove this! Fermat's Last Theorem is an enormously deep result, which only about twelve and a half people in the world understand, and you are using it to prove an almost trivial result. The reason that

$$(z-y)(z^{n-1}+z^{n-2}y+...y^{n-1}) > ((y+1)-y)nx^{n-1}$$

is that $z > y + 1$ (so $z-y > (y+1)-y$), and each of the $n$ terms $z^{n-r}y^{r-1}$ is $ \ge x^{n-1}$ (because $z > x$ and $y \ge x$).

(There is a misprint in your question: $z^{n-2}$ should be $z^{n-2}y$.)

Comment: Thanks @TonyK, if it is not too much, can I ask how do people think of such inequalities. I mean I would never have thought of $nx^{n-1}$ ever by myself.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $x\le y < z$ in your assuming.

Comment: I am sorry, I still don't get it.

Comment: Just replace $y$ or $z$ with $x$.